# Send an email notification via Gmail SMTP server using SSL connection

Tags: java, smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an email notification via Gmail SMTP server using SSL connection. But no email is getting. Even no error is reported there.My method `send()` is giving below.Please help.I am using JSF2 .

```
public void send()
{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("userName","password");
        }
    });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("nid@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("arun@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler," +
                "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly is JSF2 related to this? Are you implying that this works properly when executed in a plain Java application with a `main()` method? If it even fails as such, then it's completely unrelated to JSF2 and you need to remove the JSF2 tag.

Comment: Ok.But this is not in a `main()`. I was calling this this `send()` somewhere.

Comment: I think you didn't understood me. Copy this code inside a `main()` method and execute it as normal Java applicaiton. If you get exactly the same problem, then it is not related to JSF2 at all. After all, executing as a normal Java application also allows for much quicker and easier developing/testing. Once you get it to work, all you need to do is to just import/call the standalone Java class in your JSF2 action method.

Comment: Using a correct Google username and password the code above works without any problems here and I receive the created E-Mail.

Answer (score 2):

This code is overly complex.  The JavaMail FAQ has [sample code for using Gmail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).
It also has [tips for debugging your problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).

One particular issue is that you should use Session.getInstance instead of
Session.getDefaultInstance.